# Browser Compatibility

Tags: cross-browser

My code works fine in Chrome, however when I run it in Firefox, there is a problem. My webpage has 2 roman style columns ( each column consists of 2 images, a top and a bottom )that run vertically from the bottom of the header to the top of the footer. But in Firefox they stop about 30px from the top of the footer, leaving a gap.
 My code does not include any vender prefixer's, but when I ran my CSS through Autoprefixer.com it did not add any either. Here is the code that seems to be affected.

```
<!--Roman Columns-->
<div class="content"> 

<div id="col_topleft">
  <img src="imagesC/col_topleft.png" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_topright">
  <img src="imagesC/col_topright.png" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_bottleft">
<img src="imagesC/col_bottleft.png" alt="column" height="685" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_bottright">
<img src="imagesC/col_bottright.png" alt="column" height="685" width="60">
</div>


   /*Roman Columns*/
   #col_topleft {position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 25px;
}       

#col_topright {position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    right: 25px;
}

#col_bottleft {position: absolute;
    top: 640px;
    left: 25px;
}       

#col_bottright {position: absolute;
    top: 640px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This code excerpt does not have the problem you describe. I tested in Chrome and firefox. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEQKCPY79Y1J As a side note, I would suggest having just one div for the left and one for the right. Then having a top and bottom within each. Then in your css, only define a position for the left and right divs.

Comment: @htr5   Thanks for your help, however I'm not sure how you concluded that my code does not have the problem I described. I looked at the code in W3schools also, however the excerpt of code does not include the footer. When I run all my code in Firefox, I assure you it has the problem just as I described it. That is to say that the columns stop 30 px short of the top of the footer.

Comment: It would help to see the full code including the header. Often it is something else causing the problem

Comment: @htr5   Here is all my code. The problem is worse when I run it in ie., and gets worse each time I refresh the page. Not sure if I leave more blank lines than most people, I do it because I have bad eyesight. It's probably already obvious, but please remember when you answer that I am a real noob. This is my second webpage.

Comment: @htr5   I tried to paste all my code here, and it would not allow me to. Said that I had too many characters. Like 2400 too many. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: @Saeed Ludeen  I re posted my question as "Code only works in Chrome"     and included all my code if you care to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem.

First add a div with position:relative than drop your content inside that div

```
 <div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute"> <!-- your content div -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I re posted my question as "Code only works in Chrome" and included all my code if you care to take a look. Not sure if I did it right , but I tried your solution, and was not able to make it work.